CompileDaemon does not compile the latest change automatically
So I have a service which fetches the data from db and has some filteration. for sake of simplicity I create a rest service with in memory data.
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

// User represents the user data structure
type User struct {
    Name        string `json:"name"`
    Address     string `json:"address"`
    Age         int    `json:"age"`
    Designation string `json:"designation"`
}

// Predefined user data
var users = []User{
    {"John Doe", "123 Main St", 30, "Software Engineer"},
    {"Jane Smith", "456 Elm St", 25, "Data Scientist"},
    {"Alice Johnson", "789 Oak St", 28, "Product Manager"},
    {"Bob Brown", "101 Maple St", 35, "Designer"},
    {"Charlie Davis", "202 Pine St", 40, "Architect"},
    {"Diana Evans", "303 Cedar St", 32, "HR Manager"},
    {"Evan Foster", "404 Birch St", 29, "Marketing Specialist"},
    {"Fiona Green", "505 Walnut St", 27, "Sales Manager"},
    {"George Harris", "606 Chestnut St", 33, "Business Analyst"},
    {"Hannah White", "707 Spruce St", 31, "Operations Manager"},
}

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()

    // GET endpoint to fetch user data
    router.GET("/users1", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, users)
    })

    // POST endpoint to add new user data
    router.POST("/users", func(c *gin.Context) {
        var newUser User
        if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&newUser); err != nil {
            c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
            return
        }
        users = append(users, newUser)
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, newUser)
    })

    router.Run(":8082")
}

Issue: The doc says to compile the main.go file to main.exe first using:
CompileDaemon -command="C:\\GoProject\\clip\\main.exe"

Then run : CompileDaemon -command=".\\main.exe"
But I want my program to pick the changes as soon as I make the hnages, I dont want to re-compile my code again and again manually.

You probably should let the "CompileDeamon" (whatever that may be) compile your code.
